# Key binding for pipe in ESS

Tags: key-bindings, ess

I am trying to define keymapping about `%>%` for ess R mode.
Code 1 is my `init.el` based on [How to implement the piping operator %>% in ESS mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/how-to-implement-the-piping-operator-in-ess-mode). After evaluation of the code, I get the key binding Code 2. I don't know why such a situation happen and `RET` does not work well. How do I fix it?

Code 1

```
(defun then_R_operator ()
  (interactive)
  (just-one-space 1)
  (insert "%>%"))

(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-%") 'then_R_operator)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "C-%") 'then_R_operator)
```

Code 2

```
key             binding
---             -------
RET     then_R_operator
C-%     then_R_operator
```

**Update**

I also try a different method as follows. But, I got the same result.

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-M") "%>%")
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "C-M") "%>%")
```

Comment: Are you using the graphical Emacs, or are you running it in a terminal? It could be that your terminal doesn't support `C-%`, and it's getting treated as RET instead

Comment: I am using the graphical Emacs.

Comment: You can't bind `C-M`, it sends the same symbol as `RET`. Your original version works as expected for me with `C-%`. Maybe you had `C-M` bound somewhere as well, that would have caused the problem.

Comment: Yes! ```C-M``` is Rstudio's keybinding. I didn't think this cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59251402/how-to-set-up-custom-automatic-character-replacement-in-emacs-ess.

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-%") "%>%")
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "C-%") "%>%")
```

Note `C-M` causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to define the key binding is with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package):

```lisp
(use-package ess
  :bind (:map ess-r-mode-map
         ("C-c >" . " %>% ")
         :map inferior-ess-r-mode-map
         ("C-c >" . " %>% ")))
```